# BigQuery: how to convert this legacy SQL to standardSQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data import pipeline into BigQuery tables (the hourly tables named transactions_20170616_00 transactions_20170616_01 ... and there are more daily/weekly/... rollups), want to use a single view to always point to the latest one, found hard to do one static standardSQL view to point to latest, my current solution is to update the view's content to `SELECT * FROM project.dataset.transactions_201706....` after every import successful,

Till I read this httparchive's latest view: it's all what I want but in legacy SQL; my project uses all standardSQL only, and prefer standardSQL because it's the future; wonder anyone knows how to convert this legacy SQL to standardSQL? then I won't need to constantly update my view
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/httparchive:runs.latest_requests?tab=details

```
SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_QUERY(httparchive:runs,
      "table_id IN (
         SELECT table_id FROM [httparchive:runs.__TABLES__]
                                 WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, '2.*requests$')
                                 ORDER BY table_id DESC LIMIT 1)")
```

following this guide, I'm trying to use
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#the_table_query_function

```
#standardSQL

SELECT * FROM `httparchive.runs.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN
( SELECT table_id
  FROM httparchive.runs.__TABLES__
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_id, r'2.*requests$')
  ORDER BY table_id DESC
  LIMIT 1)
```

but the query failed of

```
Query Failed
Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix. Matched views are: httparchive:runs.latest_pages, httparchive:runs.latest_pages_mobile, httparchive:runs.latest_requests, httparchive:runs.latest_requests_mobile
Job ID: bidder-1183:bquijob_1400109e_15cb1dc3c0c
```

I found the wildcard can only be used at last? in this case why not  `SELECT * FROM httparchive.runs.*_requests WHERE ...` work?

in this case, is it saying **the Wildcard Tables feature in standardSQL isn't same flexible as TABLE_QUERY in legacySQL>?**

Comment: the inner query `SELECT table_id ...` get exactly what I want, httparchive's current latest is `2017_05_15_requests`; but why this not work?

```sql
SELECT * FROM httparchive.runs.(
SELECT table_id
  FROM httparchive.runs.__TABLES__
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_id, r'2.*requests$')
  ORDER BY table_id DESC
  LIMIT 1 )
```